# Google Cloud returns error "Access Not Configured. Compute Engine API has not been used in project xx before or it is disabled

Tags: r, google-cloud-platform, rstudio, google-compute-engine

I have been trying to set up Google Cloud Engine on Rstudio through Mark Edmonson's GoogleEngineR package and have run into a problem. When I run gce_get_project() it returns this error:

```
Request Status Code: 403
Error: API returned: Access Not Configured. Compute Engine API has not been used in project xxx
before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/compute.googleapis.com/overview?project=xxx then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.
```

I start the script with the library(googleComputeEngineR) command and this is what it returns.

```
Setting scopes to https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
Successfully auto-authenticated via C:/Users/jonah/Documents/R_scripts/discount-fireworks/gcp_key.json
Set default project ID to 'xxx1'
Set default zone to 'asia-southeast1'
```

I followed the instructions in the vignette to the letter, so I'm guessing it means I've successfully authenticated? The instruction states to define the settings in a .Renviron text file in the home directory. This is what mine looks like:

```
GCE_AUTH_FILE="C:/Users/jonah/Documents/R_scripts/discount-
fireworks/gcp_key.json"
GCE_DEFAULT_PROJECT_ID="xxx1"
GCE_DEFAULT_ZONE="asia-southeast1"
```

Apparently this is supposed to help auto authenticate upon loading from the library. I've looked up past solutions but I've tried them all. Compute Engine API has been enabled in my console. Billing has also been enabled. When I visit the url defined in the error, this is what I see.

[image]

Entering g cloud compute instances list returns 0 items.

[image]

Does anyone know how to resolve this error? I'm new to Google Cloud; any help is appreciated.

Comment: Show the code/commands that generate this error. The Google Cloud Console does not use .Renviron file. Try this command to verify if the API is enabled: `gcloud compute instances list`

Comment: I've updated the question - I'm using the .Renviron file for Rstudio. When I try gcloud compute instances list it returns nothing. Is it a problem with the R package, with my package settings, or my GCP settings?

Answer (score 0):

If the Compute Engine API was not enabled, you would get an error.
The message you are seeing is just listing the number of GCE
instances you currently have running. Do you have a VM instance
running within Compute Engine ? If not, then the output is correct."

"The gcloud command seems to be running fine."

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer, but I managed to get around this by abandoning the googlecomputeengineR package and creating a VM for Rstudio directly on google cloud. It works perfectly and resolves the niggling issues with the R package.

There's a wonderful tutorial here: https://grantmcdermott.com/2017/05/30/rstudio-server-compute-engine/